spring mvc thymeleaf, populate more than one value with select option
Abstracted template code is
<form action="#" th:action="@{/formPost}" th:object="${modelAttribute}" method="post">
    <select th:onchange="this.form.submit()" id="modelAttributeFieldA" name="modelAttributeFieldA">
        <option th:each="formDataItem : ${formDataItems}"
                th:text="${formDataItem.field1}"
                th:value="${formDataItem.field2}"></option>
    </select>
</form>

I now want to populate more than one value to modelAttribute, not just the modelAttributeFieldA.
Is this possible?
Adding comma separated th:attr to the options like in
th:attr="modelAttributeFieldA=${formDataItem.field1},modelAttributeFieldB=${formDataItem.field2},modelAttributeFieldC=${formDataItem.field3}"

and reducing the select to th:onchange="this.form.submit()" did not do the trick.

There isn't a way to do this with Thymeleaf.  I thin the best you are going to get is something like using JavaScript to copy the value to 2 other <input type="hidden" /> fields.
